# why to use singlequotes and \ in the patterens in grep command?

Tags: grep

In some book I have seen a grep command example as

$grep '^no(fork\|group)' /etc/group

I need explanation for "why to use single quotes for the patteren and \ before the characters ( | )".

Comment: Hint: Escape special characters in grep

Comment: using singlequotes prevents intrepretation of special characters then what is the need of using \ befroe (|)

Comment: See [Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards) (section Standards) in Wikipedia and specifically the difference between basic and extended POSIX syntax

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of using single quotes with grep, is that you do not need to escape double quotes when you need to grep for them. For example, if you wanted to search for `"findthis"` (including searching for the quotes) with grep, using single quotes, it would look like this:

```
grep '"findthis"' yourfile.txt
```

If you were using double quotes you would need to escape the quotes with a `\`, so it would look like this:

```
grep "\"findthis\"" yourfile.txt
```

The reason a backslash is needed to search for certain characters is that grep assumes that those characters have special meanings. For example grep uses `"` to find out the beginning and end of what you are searching for (among other things). But that means that you cannot ever search for `"` unless there is some way around this. The solution is to place a `\` before the `"` like so: `\"`. If you do that, then grep knows that you actually want to search for `"` rather than end the string.

Answer (score 0):

quoting arguments for a command is always recommended.  single quote won't expand variable. in your example, it makes no different to use single/double quotes.

take an example:

```
kent$  cat f
foo
bar
ooo
```

without quote:

```
kent$  grep foo|bar f
zsh: correct 'bar' to 'bzr' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: bar
```

you see, my zsh thought you want to **pipe** output to a command "bar"

now why escape `|`:

Assume your `grep` is not an alias. grep use `BRE` by default, in `BRE` you need to escape some char to give them special meaning, `|` is one of them.

You can however let grep work in `ERE` or `PCRE` mode, with `-E, -P` option. then you don't need escape those char any longer:

```
kent$  grep -E 'foo|bar' f
foo
bar
```

in `ERE` or `PCRE`, you escape some char, to take the special meaning away.